# Extracting Xpath or RegEx in Jmeter for a verification token?

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter

I am trying to use a RegEx Extractor in a get HTTP request for a login page with Users, Passwords and Verification tokens. The tokens are my problem.

I am using this in my Regular Expression Extractor:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="()" >
```

I want to use the value on a post I have created the parameter as this in the login `${__RequestVerificationToken}` & a UDV in the get with name `__Requestverificationtoken` and value `${setProperty}`.

None of this is working.
What am I missing?

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you clarify what you receive, what regexp you use and show examples ?

Comment: Any news on this , you should accept answer if it was helpful

Comment: PMD I am using the below but it does not work I receive this message: __RequestVerificationToken=%24%7B__RequestVerificationToken%7D&

Comment: Show what the response that is supposed to contain RequestVerificationToken contains, and show also where you put your regular expression extractor , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You regexp syntax is wrong.

If for example your page contains this:

You can extract it with this:

[image]

You can use it with:

> ${RequestVerificationToken}

Comment: This worked for me. It should be accepted as the answer.